# WPF bind textblock to parent property

Tags: wpf, xaml

I know this type of question has been answered previously, but I just started with `WPF` a week ago. I have the following scenario where i need to bind a `Textblock`'s `Text` property to it's parent `Grid`'s `Width` property entirely from XAML. So, if the `Gird`'s `Width` is `50`, then `Textblock`'s `Text` value should be `50` as well. Below is my XAML :

```
 <Grid x:Name=MyGrid" Margin="112,11,0,0">
  <Rectangle x:Name="ColorRect" Fill="Blue" Width="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
  <TextBlock x:Name="ValueTextBlock" Text=""/>
 </Grid>
```

Is it possible to bind the `Text` property of the `Textblock` to the `Grid`'s(myGrid) `Width` property and also include a `%` at the end of the text ? Say, if `Width` = `50` ,then `TextBlock`'s `Text` would be `50%` ??
Any help will be appreciated as i am totally new to this.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: @Clemens , i am totally new, i have no idea what to try within the XAML, can you please atleast provide a link to an example ?

Comment: There are tons of books and online tutorials available. How about reading an introductory book about WPF? StackOverflow is the wrong place for this kind of question.

Comment: @Clemens , i am in a great shortage of time...Can you please atleast provide a link to such scenario so that i can solve it fast ? Then i will move on to read the book..Pleasee

Comment: That's bad, since [Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview) takes a couple of minutes to read and understand.

Comment: @Clemens , well i think he has very less time lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it is very very easy to bind a property to a parent's property. Here's a sample :

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding (Grid.Width),
RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}"/>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Or just ElementName... Would also work for non-ancestors.

Comment: @Clemens , gave extra details so that he can have more topics to research and learn ... :)

Comment: @Clemens , however, OP asked if he could add a `%` at the end, i never had to do that, do you have any idea how to do it ?

Comment: Take a look at StringFormat. I hate this spoon feeding.

Comment: @Clemens , yeah !! Just remembered of `MultiBinding` too :) Thanks